# Is there an overview of fields in datasets of custom (word) reports in Dynamics Business Central

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

Somehow i have the feeling its difficult to get detailed information about Dynamics BC. I am currently "designing" some custom reports - e.g. our invoices - using word templates.

Now I would like to add some data from BC to the report that I can not find as available  Field/content control in the provided "XML Custom Part" (e.g. our BIC or the clients german UST-ID (VAT ID))

Therefore:
a) Is there an overview of the available Fields in the XML Part? In best case with there mapping to the corresponding Fields in BC Frontend?
b) Can I extend the available Fields in the XML Part?

Answer (score 0):

One report can use data from multiple tables, you can also have bespoke data in there ( aka variables calculated on the fly) so the answer is yes, you can if you have access to the web client ([how to inspect a page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-inspecting-pages?tabs=page)) but you wouldn't know where to look!
So ask the consultant or another developer where is the field that you are looking for